# validation for filing shift request (for workers) in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, validation

i'm new here and in dealing with sql server

i need to add a proc in sql that is checking if worker said he cant work over 4 shift in one week sql will print a messege..

i got something like this:

```
create proc proc_eror_worker_request

@max_ccwshift int output,
@bla int output

as

set @max_ccwshift=4
if exists(select*from dbo.Request  having  count(dbo.Request.Date_CantWork)>@max_ccwshift )
    begin 
        print 'wokers submited litle shifts'                
        set @bla=count(dbo.Request.Date_CantWork)
        select @bla
        from  dbo.Request

        return 1
    End
        Else
            begin
            print 'everything is OK!'
            return 0            
        End
Go
```

i'm new at this.. so please help me

thanks in advance..

Comment: To be honest, what you've supplied here doesn't really look like valid SQL. Having needs to be used with an aggregate function. The "set @bla = " line makes no real sense. You're not filtering by worker ID, or by date.

Comment: I would usually recommend writing the query first, then wrapping it in a stored procedure. Your query will need a bunch of parameters - don't worry about those until you've got the query running nicely.The query JNK suggests will help - you will also need to add a filter for week because right now, you're searching for all cant work requests.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are close-ish to what you are after.  Have you tried running this?

A **MAJOR** issue I see is that you don't have any selection for which worker you are looking at.  I'm assuming there should be some filter like

`WHERE Worker_ID = xxx`

otherwise you are checking all the workers in the table and will get some strange results.

One other problem I see is here:

```
print 'wokers submited litle shifts'                
set @bla=count(dbo.Request.Date_CantWork)
select @bla
from  dbo.Request
```

I'm guessing that would return a syntax error.  It should be:

```
print 'wokers submited litle shifts'                
select @bla=count(Date_CantWork)
from  dbo.Request
```

What do you get if you run it as you wrote it?

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure proc_eror_worker_reqwest, Line 9
The multi-part identifier "dbo.Request.Date_CantWork" could not be bound.                this is the eror. i will try to run your code and add worker id

Comment: That's because you need to just reference the field inside that `COUNT` function.  It sounds like you have a lot to learn about SQL.  I would **STRONGLY** recommend that you break this down into smaller pieces, run those individually MANUALLY, then put them back together in a proc.  You don't build a car until you are sure all the parts work.

Comment: that's a good suggestion :)  ... i dont like sql but it is importent, i guess...anyway, now it is runing...but i try to do this: declare @bla int
exec proc_eror_worker_reqwest 325789657 
select 'Num of Students with grade under 55 is: ' as 'Num of Students', @bla as 'Answer'
go      and i get this eror: Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure proc_eror_worker_reqwest, Line 0
Procedure or function 'proc_eror_worker_reqwest' expects parameter '@max_ccwshift', which was not supplied.

(1 row(s) affected)

Comment: @Liron - Your stored proc definition lists 2 parameters.  If you alway want it to be 4 days, then change that to a `DECLARE...` variable instead of a parameter in you proc.